# How to truncate a parameter from the URL address line, right after processing it?

Tags: php

I want to send traffic to my website, into this link:

`mydomain.com/?foo=1&bar=1`

This page should have a code that checks for the `bar` parameter, and modifies the content of the page according their value, for example:

```
if(isset($_GET['bar']));

switch ($_GET['bar']) {

    case "1":
        $var = "a";
        break;

    case "2":
        $var = "b";
        break;

    default:
        $var = "c";
}

<?php echo $var; ?>
```

However, after this content modification, I want the URL address line of the browser, to show only this URL:

`mydomain.com/?foo=1`

The reason is this:

After reaching my page, I want to give the visitor an option to visit another third party website. I want the third party to know which page the visitor came from, but I don't want the third party to know about the existence of the `bar` parameter.

Comment: you have to go with .htaccess

Comment: htaccess would be a decent way of solving your problem, another option is to store the `bar` value in a session and redirect to `mydomain.com/?foo=1` then use `$_SESSION['bar']` to change the page.

Comment: If i am not wrong, you first want to redirect to mydomain.com/?foo=1&bar=1 then again redirect to mydomain.com/?foo=1 without the bar parameter right??

Comment: @WilliamFrancisGomes yes

Comment: Ok, then you first go to mydomain.com/?foo=1&bar=1 link and after completing your work or coding, redirect again to mydomain.com/?foo=1 using header. Sounds good?

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();    
if(isset($_GET['bar'])){
    $_SESSION['bar']=$_GET['bar'];
    header("Location: mydomain.php?foo=".$_GET['foo']);
}
```

then

```
session_start();
switch ($_SESSION['bar']) {

        case "1":
            $var = "a";
            break;

        case "2":
            $var = "b";
            break;

        default:
            $var = "c";
    }

    echo $var;
```

Comment: Two questions: 1. wouldn't using header redirects hurt the user experience? 2. the 'foo' parameter is not constant, it might be `foo1' `foo2`, `foo1=1&foo2=2&bar=1`, so I will need some way to simply keep anything else than `bar`, no matter what it looks like.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but have you tried unset($_GET['bar']) ?